# Numpy with multiple where conditions [TypeError: invalid type promotion]

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use multiple where conditions(mentioned below) in order to output a final date.

```
np.where( (loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')>0.0) & (loan_plans.principal_outstanding.astype('float')<1000.0), loan_plans.max_repaid_date, 
     (np.where( (loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')>0.0) & (loan_plans.principal_outstanding.astype('float')>1000.0), pd.to_datetime('today')
               (np.where( loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')<0.0, loan_plans.final_repayment_date, 0.0)))))
```

These are the datatypes for the other variables

```
loan_plans.max_repaid_date=datetime64[ns]
loan_plans.final_repayment_date = datetime64[ns]
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: invalid type promotion

I think the problem is regarding the data types and is a relatively small error, but I have been searching and can't find information to help me solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried each `astype` expression by itself?  Often the best way of debugging a large expression is to test each component until you find the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. I did this and figured out the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer. The problem was with the pd.to_datetime('today') part. This had to be changed to reflect the data types of the other datetime parts

```
loan_plans['final_date'] = np.where( (loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')>=0) & (loan_plans.principal_outstanding.astype('float')<1000), pd.to_datetime(loan_plans['max_repaid_date']),
     np.where( (loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')>0) & (loan_plans.principal_outstanding.astype('float')>1000), np.datetime64('today'),
               np.where( loan_plans.days_since_end.astype('timedelta64[D]')<0, pd.to_datetime(loan_plans['final_repayment_date']), pd.to_datetime(loan_plans['final_repayment_date']))))
```